# What does the JSON look like?

Tags: php, json, curl

```
$post = array('param1'=>'aaa', 'param2'=>'bbb', 'param3'=>'ccc');
```

I am doing some cURL in php this is part of a POST call.
Suppose the above array is transformed into JSON what would the JSON string look like?

Comment: `echo json_encode($post);` and find out :)

Answer (score 0):

it would look like this, if it was indeed JSON:

```
{"param1":"aaa","param2":"bbb","param3":"ccc"}
```

But it's not.

Comment: It would if curl actually used JSON format as he assumed. But his assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide an array as `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, not sent as JSON, it's sent in `multipart/form-data` format. It would look like:

```
--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="param1"

aaa
--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="param2"

bbb
--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="param3"

ccc
--AaB03x
```

Where `AaB03x` is a random boundary string that's specified in the header:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x
```

See the W3C [Forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) specification.